# Using Navteq maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

1.Is it possible to NOT use Google Maps in Android?
2. Can we use Navteq maps?
3. What will it take to write such an application?
4. Do we have to come up with our own version of MapView?

Pointers and links that can answer these questions and help me get started on 4. are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSMDroid provides an opensource alternative to Google Maps. They have their own implementation of `MapView` (similar to Google's implementation).

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

Answer (score 1):

Most likely NDrive use NAVTEQ's map, at least in some areas

Answer (score 0):

there are some applications on the market that are custom maps, i.e. YandexMaps, OpenStreetMap & others

I believe they had written their own map class implementation, not a MapView one.

Comment: So it is possible to use other Maps.